Is there a way to rename the bands of a Raster in Rasters.jl?
This is the Raster I am using:
 30097×19617×4 Raster{UInt8,3} │
├───────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── dims ┐
  ↓ X    Projected{Float64} LinRange{Float64}(12.996604689820469, 13.00021446808493, 30097) ForwardOrdered Regular Intervals{Start},
  → Y    Projected{Float64} LinRange{Float64}(51.65934139687541, 51.657878092285806, 19617) ReverseOrdered Regular Intervals{Start},
  ↗ Band Categorical{Int64} 1:4 ForwardOrdered

I want to change the values of Band from 1 to "Red", 2 to "Green", 3 to "Blue" and 4 to "Alpha".
Any suggestions?

The Raster struct and its dims tuple is not mutable, so a Raster's dimensions cannot be modified in place.
It is possible to rebuild a Raster with a differently indexed dimension around the same data, such as Bands created with modify.
An example raster with numbered bands:
using DimensionalData, Rasters

xCount = 9   # 30097
yCount = 7   # 19617

data = rand(UInt8, xCount, yCount, 4)

xRange = LinRange(12.996604689820469, 13.00021446808493, xCount)
yRange = LinRange(51.65934139687541, 51.657878092285806, yCount)
bandRange = 1:4

dimData = DimArray(data, (X=xRange, Y=yRange, Bands=bandRange))

rasterWithNumberedBands = Raster(dimData)

Rebuild as raster with symbol names of Bands, keeping the same data:
bandSymbols = [:Red, :Green, :Blue, :Alpha]

@assert length(bandRange) == length(bandSymbols)

rasterWithSymbolNamedBands =
    rebuild(rasterWithNumberedBands,
            dims = map(rasterWithNumberedBands.dims) do dim
                     if :Bands == name(dim)
                       modify(dimRange -> bandSymbols, dim)
                     else
                       dim
                     end
                   end)

Compare indexing by integer and indexing by a symbol
rasterWithNumberedBands[:, :, 3] == rasterWithSymbolNamedBands[:, :, At(:Blue)]

(The Bands of rasterWithSymbolNamedBands can still be indexed with an integer or integer range.)
rasterWithSymbolNamedBands[:, :, 3]
rasterWithSymbolNamedBands[:, :, 1:3]


Thanks a lot! I am coming from R and my brain still doesn't want to adopt...
